# How to create new object in a for loop?

Tags: java, object, keyboard

I want to create some objects in a program using for loop. The parameters of the objects are accepted from key board. My question is how to create different objects in a for loop. Here is what I have.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TimeToGraduate {

public static void main(String[] args){

    class Course{
        Course (String name, String sem, int numOfPre){
            this.name = name;
            this.sem = sem;
            this.numOfPre = numOfPre;
        }
        String name;
        String sem;
        int numOfPre;
    }

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input two integers here: ");
    String totalCourse = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] numOfCourse = totalCourse.split(" ");//[0] num of total course  [1] max num per semester

    for(int i = 0;i < Integer.parseInt(numOfCourse[0]); i++){
        System.out.print("Please input course info here: ");
        String courseInfo = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] infoOfCourse = courseInfo.split(" ");

        String courseName = infoOfCourse[0];
        String courseSem = infoOfCourse[1];
        int courseNumOfPre = Integer.parseInt(infoOfCourse[2]);

        Course course = new Course(courseName,courseSem,courseNumOfPre);

 //How to create different objects?

    }

    scanner.close();
}
}
```

Comment: You *are* creating an object: `Course course = new Course(/.../);`  But you're not *doing anything* with that object.  Was there something you wanted to *do* with it?

Comment: Yes, I want to add all the courses object to a graph to do the topological sort. But first I need to create them.

Comment: Well, what's stopping you from "adding all the courses to a graph"?  Where do you attempt to do that?  Again, you ***are*** "creating them".  You're just not doing anything with them.

Comment: I have not done it. So there is just what I have here.

Comment: So you're asking how to "add a course to a graph to do the topological sort"?  You should really specify that in the question to be more clear.  Additionally, you'll want to specify what that actually means.  There's nothing in the code about any "graph".  Are you using some specific 3rd party product?  Something custom?  The question is lacking *a lot* of information.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the objects you are creating in an array.

Before the for loop:

```
// create an empty array with the size of the total courses
int numOfCourses = Integer.parseInt(numOfCourse[0]);
Course courses[] = new Course[numOfCourses];
```

Inside the loop:

```
courses[i] = new Course(courseName, courseSem, courseNumOfPre);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Collection

The [answer by Securo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043161/642706) is correct. But rather than an array, it is more flexible and powerful to use a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). If you want to keep the objects in the order of their creation, use the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface, with an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) as the implementation.

Before the loop starts, define an empty List.

```
List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you know the number of courses, pass that number as the initial size of the `ArrayList`. Helps performance and memory usage a little bit if the ArrayList need not be resized.

```
List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>( numberOfCourses );
```

In your loop, instantiate the objects and add to the List.

```
Course course = new Course( … );
courses.add( course );
```